# Build Docker image that used JAVA 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have been working with Spring boot and Docker. I used to build docker image of applications on JAVA 8. But now i need to build the docker image of application that use JAVA 11. Please guide me about this.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8u121-jdk-alpine
ENV APP_JAR_NAME applicationTest
RUN apk --update add curl bash && 
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir /app
ADD ${APP_JAR_NAME}.jar /app/
ADD run.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]
CMD ["/app/run.sh"]
```

> **Request**
>   please share the Dockerfile that i could used for building docker image of **JAVA 11**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change version (**FROM**) to [adoptopenjdk/openjdk11](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11), from the *Overview*:

```sh
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY japp.jar /opt/app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/japp.jar"]
```

Comment: where to expose the port no sir ?

Comment: just change `FROM openjdk:8u121-jdk-alpine` to `FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest` in your `Dockerfile`, other things in `Dockerfile` works in the same way - `EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: sir may I right your code exactly ? Is this works the same as already written code works?

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram yes, you can change the version of the `java` to the one you need without the rest of the changes

Comment: This saved me hours of debugging when setting up a hack